# Easily change screen resolution in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, resolution

Is there a program that sits in the system tray and lets you easily change the screen resolution in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

**[Resolution Changer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Resolution-Changer-Pallos.shtml)** is a resolution changer program. Lists all available resolutions of the display. Sets the maximum frequency available at the selected resolution.

[image]

If you fancy something more powerful, then I'd recommend **[PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm)**, but it isn't free.

Answer (score 2):

[Screen Mode Switch](http://micromighty.com/Products/Screen_Mode_Switch.aspx) allows you to easily change resolutions from the system tray, and also define custom hotkeys to change resolutions. You can easily make custom resolution profiles with your desired personal settings.

[image]

[image]

The personal version is free for non-commercial use.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in Windows 7.

Comment: What error are you receiving? You could try vista compatibility mode.