# Is there a widget to adjust display resolution in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, resolution, accessibility

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Easily change screen resolution in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/111426/easily-change-screen-resolution-in-windows-7)
>   [Any way of changing Windows 7 screen resolution via command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/89302/any-way-of-changing-windows-7-screen-resolution-via-command-line)

I'm setting up a Windows 7 Home box for my parents, and I'd need a way to add a shortcut on the desktop that would launch some adjustment control, which in turn would easily adjust the resolution to their reading pleasure levels.

Actually, the best way would be to pre-program a few resolution settings into separate buttons, so they could just click "small", "medium" or "large" (small being the native resolution)

Does anyone use something like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easily change screen resolution in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/111426/easily-change-screen-resolution-in-windows-7), usable info to make shortcuts: [Any way of changing Windows 7 screen resolution via command line?](http://superuser.com/questions/89302/any-way-of-changing-windows-7-screen-resolution-via-command-line)

Comment: NP. The Search box is our friend. ;)

Comment: @Sonic Soul, which solution did you use?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a widget but how to geek suggest [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17604/change-desktop-resolution-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/) software for changing on a hotkey.  It's not exactly what your after but it's the closest I could find.